# History of Available Stock in SAP B1

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, report, reporting, sapb1

How can I find what was the available stock on a specific date in the past?

I know how to get OnHand for any date in the past:

```
    SELECT LocType, LocCode, ItemCode, SUM(InQty-OutQty) [OnHand]
    From OIVL
    Where DocDate <= '7/7/2017'
        AND ITEMCODE = 'xyz' 
    Group by LocType, LocCode, ItemCode
```

But this does not account for what was committed. It shows what was on hand, but not what was actually available (OnHand - Committed = Available). So, how could I get to this "Available" number for dates in the past?

Thanks!

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers. Note that `tsql` narrows the choices, but does not specify the database.

Comment: It wouldn't let me create good tags for the post because I'm too new of a user. An sap-business-one or business-one-9.2 tag would be nice since this is more an SAP B1 schema/taxonomy question independent of database or other technologies

Comment: what is (OnHand - Committed = Available) in terms of dB schema?

Comment: Within SAP tables, I am wondering how to find Committed number for a point in the past. I know how to get Committed for the current date, looking at sales orders and stock transfers. How can I see what was "committed" on some day six months ago? I'm thinking it might involved mining the histories of sales orders and stock transfers. It would be nice if their was an easier way or if someone had a query to do this already

Comment: I still haven't found a good answer on how to get the history of stock changes for OnHand/OnOrder/isCommitted/Available.

For now I ended up setting up slowly changing dimension on these stock attributes. It doesn't get us history for the past, but we can start generating history for more accuracy moving forward

Answer (score 3):

In case this helps anyone else.... here is an example of how to get your item quantity and cost history in SAP BusinessOne. Pass the date and item you want to see history for into the function. If you omit item code it returns all items.

```html
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnStockAndCostHistory]
( 
 @EndDate DATETIME, @ItemCode NVARCHAR(255) = 'All'
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
 WITH Cost AS (
  SELECT
   OINM.TransNum,
   OINM.ItemCode,
   OINM.Warehouse,
   OINM.Balance,
   OINM.CreateDate
  FROM OINM (NOLOCK)
   JOIN OITM (NOLOCK) ON OITM.ItemCode = OINM.ItemCode
   JOIN OITB (NOLOCK) ON OITM.ItmsGrpCod=OITB.ItmsGrpCod
  WHERE  OINM.CreateDate <= @EndDate

 ),
 FinalCostByWarehouse AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM Cost 
  WHERE TransNum = (
   SELECT MAX(TransNum)
   FROM Cost sub
   WHERE Cost.ItemCode = sub.ItemCode
    AND Cost.Warehouse = sub.Warehouse)
 ),
 Quantity AS (
  SELECT
   OINM.ItemCode,
   OINM.Warehouse,
   SUM(OINM.InQty) - SUM(OINM.OutQty) [Qty]
  FROM OINM (NOLOCK)
   JOIN OITM (NOLOCK) ON OITM.ItemCode = OINM.ItemCode
   JOIN OITB (NOLOCK) ON OITM.ItmsGrpCod=OITB.ItmsGrpCod
  WHERE OINM.CreateDate <= @EndDate
  group by OINM.ItemCode, OINM.Warehouse
 )
 SELECT 
  OITW.ItemCode,
  OITW.WhsCode,
  c.Balance [Cost],
  q.Qty [Quantity]
 FROM OITW
  LEFT JOIN FinalCostByWarehouse c ON OITW.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
   AND OITW.WhsCode = c.Warehouse
  LEFT JOIN Quantity q ON OITW.ItemCode = q.ItemCode
   AND OITW.WhsCode = q.Warehouse
 WHERE (OITW.ItemCode = @ItemCode
  OR @ItemCode = 'All')
  AND (ISNULL(c.Balance,0) > 0
   OR ISNULL(q.Qty,0) > 0)
)
```

Usage would look like:

```
SELECT *
FROM ufnStockAndCostHistory('9/15/2017','B107A-12HB')
```